# Click, Scroll to and fade in

Tags: scroll, click, hide, fadein, scrollto

I need your help with a javascript.

The status quo:

I am making a website, that kind of functions like a slide show:
Each slide consists of a header, an image and a little text. Underneath the text comes a little arrow that points down. When you click it you should scroll down to the next slide. When it scrolls down it should fade in the next header.
You can find what I've got so far here:
http://jsfiddle.net/singue/mjvky

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

The problem:
Whenever the arrow is clicked it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't scroll to the desired div. It seems pretty random.
The other problem is only with the first arrow: I have is when i click it, the next header-, image- and text-div hide but then the third slide slides up, right after the first slide. It then scrolls from the first slide to the second one, but you will see the third one while it scrolls. Why is this happening when the first arrow is being clicked and only then?

Do you have an idea how to make it work?

Thank you very much!

Yves

Comment: You should remove JS that has got nothing to do with you actual slide show. Also you should never use inline JS with the onclick attribute. Instead you should bind on certain elements using jQuery's on() method. THis way you can write generic code for your behavior instead of code for each of you elements. Yous should also format your code and use or descriptive variable names than argLength. These changes make your code easier to understand.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
to my suprise the exchange of onclick="..." with script=script=" $('#header1' ).click(){...} has solved the problem of scrolling to far. but now its not fading in anymore.

Comment: Update the code in you fiddle and do what I recommended to do. After that I can try to solve your problem.

Comment: No, you didn't not clean up your code properly. Do everything I suggested.